# theme customizations gone after enabling ssl

Tags: themes, ssl

I'm on version 5.3.2

I bought the 'kidz theme' from themeforest and install it and made many changes (changing colors, sections, order...) and all went good, last week I decided to add ssl certificate to my website, all my changes that i made to the theme are gone.. I tried to change all the links in database from http to https, I changed the Urls in `Settings > General` to https, and I installed the `Really Simple SSL` plugin.. in result links are good, some images shown normally but all changes I made to the theme are gone (mega menu, slider, custom sections and navs, sections ordering, logo, colors...) all that is gone it shows me like I just made a fresh install to that theme with it's initial logo and initial sections and ordering...

what's the wrong and how I can restore the customisations I made to this theme?

Answer (score 0):

first, disable the **Really Simple SSL** plugin add the folowing code in wp_config.php file to SSL

**define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);.**